# sql cumulative sum to group and label records

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I need help with a specific running total problem.

My table is:

```
|Quote|ID  | Seq|Code| Grp |
|-----|----|----|----|-----|
|42   |535 | 1  |    |     |
|42   |536 | 2  |  A |     |
|42   |537 | 3  |  B |     |
|42   |538 | 4  |    |     |
```

empty cells are NULL, blank or 0

'Quote' is an integer field defining the set I want to work on
'ID' is an autoincrement integer field to uniquely define added records.
'Code' is a single character field.
'Grp' is the integer field I need to update in the table according to these rules:

iterating thru the table by ID
a) for the first record in the set 'Grp' is always 1
b) 'Grp' never decreases
b) if the next record has 'Code' = NULL or  or 'A' increment Grp by 1. Otherwise set Grp to the previous value.

Result

```
|Quote|ID  | Seq|Code| Grp |
|-----|----|----|----|-----|
|42   |535 | 1  |    |  1  |
|42   |536 | 2  |  A |  2  |
|42   |537 | 3  |  B |  2  |
|42   |538 | 4  |    |  3  |
```

I know that I can use SUM() of something and an INNER JOIN to the same table, but I can't get anything to get the right result.
Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cumulative sum.  If I understand the logic correctly:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when Code is NULL or code = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by quote order by seq)
from t;
```